# RadioButton unchecked number need be changed as 0 using Java

Tags: java

i creating a simple java radio button project. if i checked the radio button result diplayed on the textbox 1.if i uncheck the radio button result need to be display 0.if i uncheck result didn't display 0.
what i tired so far i attached below.

```
int  r1marks = 0;
int  r2marks = 0;
  if(r1.isSelected())
    {
        if(r1.isSelected() == true)

    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "C#" + r1marks);
        r1marks = 1;

    }
    else
    {

        r1marks = 0;
    }
        txtmarks.setText(String.valueOf(r1marks));

    }
    else  if(r2.isSelected())
    {

   if(r2.isSelected()==true)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "VB" + r2marks);
         r2marks = 1;

    }
     else
        {

        r2marks = 0;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why do you check `r1.isSelected()` twice ?

Comment: because i have two radio button sir.

Comment: how to solve this problem sir

Comment: may be try the else block for outer if, currently you use for inner if

Comment: can you write this

Comment: For each of the 2 buttons, you do twice the same if why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, the two check on same condition does not makes sense. I think one should be removed

```
int  r1marks = 0;
int  r2marks = 0;

if(r1.isSelected()){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "C#" + r1marks);
    r1marks = 1;
} else{
    r1marks = 0;
}
txtmarks.setText(String.valueOf(r1marks));

if(r2.isSelected()){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "VB" + r2marks);
    r2marks = 1;
}else{
        r2marks = 0;
}
```

Comment: Why keeping the mistake of doing twice each rX.isSelected() ?

Comment: yes, does not make sense. Thats what i mentioned above the code.now corrected that code